# Packages or tools to manage libraries locally

Tags: software-development

Everytime when I try to setup a new environment in a Linux box for my personal development, I have to download several (mostly C, C++) libraries and compile and  install by myself. To make the development environment clean, I always put them into a separate folder, for example, ~/dev/. This is a very boring process that could take half day.

Is there a convenient way or tool that can help?

I am working under Linux OS; there's no need for the tool to be cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

Three options:

1. Build your environment and then take a snapshot before doing anything else
2. Create your own distro with all of the tools & settings that you need/like
3. Use a tool such as [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) which basically stores a starting image, or box, and a recipe to get to where you need to be - it also allows you to store the results back to a new box. Vagrant allows you to build your boxes for Docker, Virtual Box or VMWare.

Personally I would go with vagrant because the input *recipe* file is plain text so if you have got one that, say populates one specific Linux build and version and later decide you need to try the same setup built on top of a different version, or even a different distribution, you can just change the bases and build a new box to the same recipe.

Vagrant is free but the VMWare builder incurs some costs IIRC. - You might also wish to take a look at [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) from the same guys.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful. What if I just want to setup the dev. env. in other's machine, avoid restoring everything ?

Comment: @blackball - If you have a server or a shared drive holding the _base_ boxes and both have vagrant installed it should just be a matter of sharing the recipes, ideally via your version control system.